# How can I make IB create an action connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm stuck on a very frustrating problem with Xcode5's Interface Builder.  Here's the issue:

I have a .xib file which contains a number of controls:

[image]

When I control drag from any of these controls into the .h or .m files corresponding to this .xib file, I am not given the option of creating an action:

[image]

The "FilesOwner" of the .xib file is set correctly to "MessageController" which is the ViewController for the .xib file.

This is frustrating because this issue is happening not just with this specific .xib / VC pair, but with all of the files in my project.  I have already cleaned and rebuilt the project and closed and reopened XCode, but nothing seems to be working..

EDIT:

After reading your comments, I realize I should have been more specific in what I'm trying to do.  In the screenshot above I chose the UIScrollView because I was under the impression that all controls were capable of generating some actions.  So, here is a screen shot of what I am actually trying to do:

[image]

Am I making the same beginner mistake here?  Should I be assigning this action in code with something like this instead of using IB:

[textView addTarget:self
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

Any More Advice?

Thank You!

Comment: what kind of action you're expecting to have for UIScrollView ? It has delegates.

Comment: Uiscrollview doesn't have ibactions. It uses delegate methods to pass details to whoever wants them.

Comment: uhuh \*nodding head\*, to add, [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) does not inherit from the [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class like [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and hence does not have the target-action ability. Which is why Xcode won't show you options to connect it with `IBAction`s methods.

Comment: On a sidenote - why are you using xib files instead of a Storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and I think my mistake is right along those lines.  I edited the post with more details though.  Also, I'm not using a Storyboard because this is pretty old code that was originally written before Storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments indicate, there are no actions you can make for a `UIScrollView`.  If you are also having issues with actionable UI objects like `UIButtons`, `UITextFields`, etc:

Check to Make sure you have the right custom class defined for that xib file (files owner).

[image: Image1]

Also make sure that the selection for the assistant editor is set to Automatic.

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1):

`-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is possible on [`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) because it inherits from [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but **not** [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) because a `UITextView` **does not** inherit from [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and hence lacks this target-action ability.

You'd have to use the [`UITextViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) and implement `-textViewDidChange:` method to do the same thing.

```
//1
//set delegate programmatically
[textView setDelegate:self];
//or via the IB: right-click drag UITextView to `File's owner`
```

---

```
//2
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    //something happened with the textView!!
}
```

PS: You might want to rename your `UITextView` object to something other than simply `textView`.